# WinSCP Putting Files fails Code 2 but Passes File.Exists

Tags: c#-4.0, file-upload, winscp-net

I have noticed that when I go to PUT a file using WinSCP that it fails with a code 2 error stating that:

> {WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: File or folder 'fileToPut.xml' does not exist. ---> WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: System Error.
>
> Code: 2. The system cannot find the file specified
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at WinSCP.OperationResultBase.Check()
>
> at transferWinSCP(String fileName) in c:\Program.cs:line 136}

However, just before it hits this line:

```
TransferOperationResult transferResult = session.PutFiles(fileName, path, false, transferOptions);`
```

I make sure that fileName indeed exists.

Any thoughts?

Here is my code:

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
   //start Log
   session.SessionLogPath = logPath;

   //connect
   session.Open(sessionOptions);

   //upload
   TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions {TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary};
   if (File.Exists(fileName))
   {
      TransferOperationResult transferResult = session.PutFiles(fileName, path, false,  transferOptions); //put the file on the ftp server
      transferResult.Check();

      foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
      {
         Console.Write("upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently having the same issue.
however i have found that if you change the path around instead of using "\" trying "/" gets a different result sometimes. thought you might want to give it a try. but at the moment changing it around does not help for me so i'm stuck in the same boat.

Comment: Thank you G. This actually fixed my problem maybe it will fix yours as well:  'Path.GetFullPath(fileName)'

Comment: Thanks, i've found a workaround for mine for the time being but i will try it later on.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me:  `Path.GetFullPath(fileName)`